# CPU usage while uploading video

Tags: firefox, video, cpu, youtube

This may be a dumb question, but when I'm uploading video to YouTube (through the site's own upload form, in Firefox, running on Linux), I see more activity in my CPU status monitor and hear the fan spool up until the upload is done. I read in a bug report elsewhere that YouTube's upload form supposedly is not relying on Flash. Additionally, from my perspective it would appear that I am not rendering or playing a video.

So my question is basically this: why is my CPU getting heated up for what I thought was a network-intensive operation, rather than a computation-intensive operation?

Comment: During the upload process, is YouTube displaying some kind of visual preview of your upload progress? Like a small video window? That could at least partly account for the CPU usage.

Comment: Also, give us more specs about your CPU (do you have a make/model handy?). And just how high does your CPU usage go during upload? 100%? 50%?

Comment: Sorry it's taken me awhile to get back ... I have a couple of screenshots that hopefully might give some idea of both what I'm seeing in YouTube, as well as how much CPU is being used: [image 1](http://i.imgur.com/CyQBRHR.png) [image 2](http://i.imgur.com/kVjUqkB.png); also my cpu is an Intel Core i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz (sandybridge); note also that I explicitly disabled the Flash plugin before starting this upload (closing and re-opening the browser)

Comment: I habe exactly the same issue, having a macbook pro, 2020, 32GBs of ram, eGpu, everything high performance… still… notebook not gerat to use during upload progresses. Browser don't matter. Chrome, Safari, Firefox, all the same.

Comment: Same same as you guys. Uploading on my 2017 MBP just cripples it. (it seems to be somewhat better if I don't leave the uploading tab active.)